# Ng-Template not rendering my HTML content

Tags: angular

I am creating a simple app to test some stuff using observables and for some reason, when I wrap that code using an ng-template tag, the HTML simply doesn't show up.

The reason I'm using this ng-template before the div, is to use an *ngIf. Initially, I thought that the *ngIf was the problem, but when I removed that statement from the template, it still did not work. So the If is not the problem.

Any idea?

```
<!-- If I remove the <ng-template> tag, the HTML is rendered, but with it, it doesn't work -->
<ng-template>
    <div class="messages-container" *ngIf="(messagesService.errors$ | async) as errors">
        <div class="messages" *ngFor="let error of errors">{{error}}</div>
        <mat-icon class="close" (click)="onClose()">close</mat-icon>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Edit:
When I use [ngIf] instead of *ngIf it works, but I still don't understand why works whit [ngIf] and why it does not work with no condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

star syntax in structural directives like here `*ngIf` implicitly creates a template from the element that this directive is being used on. no need to explicitly write `<ng-temlate>` just use `*ngIf`

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: just remove <ng-template> from you code, and it should work just fine

Comment: But that's the point, why I can't use the <ng-template> with the start syntax nor without any structural directive?

Comment: If I change it to <ng-container> works fine

Comment: because by using <ng-template> you are creating a rule of how to create a piece of html which then you can render somewhere. but you are not rendering it anywhere. If you add [ngIf] directive to <ng-template> element, then this directive executes the logic of rendering this template 1 time. if you use [ngForOf]... on this template then it will be rendered multiple times

Comment: Now I got it. I also found this article that helped me. Your final explanation made everything more clear. Thanks!

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691/